# Get the centre point of UIStackView arranged subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uistackview, bounds

I have a custom view inside a UITableViewCell. Inside this view is a simple UIStackView with 4 images (Added programmatically). I need the centre point or the origin of each of these images relative to the UIView superview. I have tried several methods but the centre point or origin is the same for all four arranged subviews.

[image]

Here is a simplified code:

```
for i in 0...3 {
                 
   print(stepsStack.arrangedSubviews[i].frame.origin) //(0,0) for all 4
   print(stepsStack.arrangedSubviews[i].convert(stepsStack.arrangedSubviews[i].frame.origin, to: self)) //(0,0) for all 4
            
   print(stepsStack.arrangedSubviews[i].convert(stepsStack.arrangedSubviews[i].center, to: self)) //(10.0, 9.5) for all 4
   print(stepsStack.convert(stepsStack.arrangedSubviews[i].center, to: self)) //(10.0, 9.5) for all 4
                
 }
```

Comment: When did you call that method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890174/get-the-frame-of-a-uistackview-subviews/42893666 ?

Comment: From layoutSubviews of the UIView class.

Comment: Hmm, I am inside my custom UIView class, and all calculation is performed in the layoutSubviews method. Everything is laid out perfectly, but can't seem to get the centre points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Called `stepsStack.layoutIfNeeded()` before calling the above for loop.
To be clear, the stack view was added inside the `layoutSubviews` method of my custom UIView class.
Thanks Larme for the hint.